# content moves down with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an inline element divided in three parts: first for an  element with background image only. the second for the content and last one for another  with background image only too.
The HTML is

```
<span class="box-l"></span>
<span class="box-c">some text</span>
<span class="box-r"></span>
```

and the CSS:

```
.box-l{
    width: 7px;
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 10px;
    background:url(../img/c_box.png) 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px;
}
.box-r{
    width: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 5px;
    background:url(../img/c_box.png) -42px 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box-c{
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 10px;
    max-width: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background:url(../img/c_box.png) -9px 0;
}
```

when the center element have not anything, the result is the following: [image: fine result]
but when I put some text into the second element, the result is this: [image: wrong result]

Why the middle element moves down with text inside? How to I can solve this?

Comment: adding vertical-align: top; it works fine, but is it a correct solution?

Answer (score -1):

When using display: inline-block: do not forget to put vertical-align: middle; texts and to keep the row height (line-height) with the same amount of time to ensure you have vertical alignment

Comment: vertical-align:middle works only in display:table-cell? because puting this the result is the same.